# Identify this plant that's taking over my yard

Tags: identification, lawn, grass, weed-control, ground-cover

What is this plant?  This is slowly taking over my yard.  You can see from one of the pictures that it's a vining plant of some sort.  It will lay roots and then spread out.  It came in to my yard a couple years ago from a bad batch of top soil and it's been spreading ever since.

Follow up question... how do I kill it?  It did not respond to Scott's Weed and Feed.  I've been pulling it out by hand and overseeding with grass, but it's a battle I'm losing.  I need a better approach but I don't know what I'm up against.

For a climate reference, I live in western Pennsylvania.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saAKq.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]